# Append list of logged in users to a log file using crontab?

Tags: unix, cron, scripting

I need to create a basic log file through the use of a crontab job that appends a timestamp, followed by a list of logged in users. It must be at 23:59 each night.
(I have used 18 18 * * * as an example to make sure the job works for now)

So far, I have;

```
!#/bin/bash
59 23 * * * (date ; who) >> /root/userlogfile.txt
```

for my crontab script, the output;

```
Fri Dec 9 18:18:01 UTC 2022
root console 00:00 Dec 9 18:15:15
```

My required output is something similar to;

```
Fri 09 Dec 23:59:00 GMT 2022

user1   tty2    2017-11-30 22:00 (:0) 

user5   pts/1   2017-11-30 20:35 (192.168.1.1)
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Your question is tagged with both [tag:linux] and [tag:unix]. Know that the output of `who` is different for different flavours of *NIX.

Comment: @SiKing Okay, I've removed the tag. Are you suggesting these two outputs are just down to the different versions? I'm using an emulated version of JSLinux - School created.

Comment: Correct. My Mac shows your first version of output, while my Linux box shows the second version of output. You can start with `who --version` to see if they are different/same.

Comment: Okay, that drops my concern. I thought I was in the wrong. Thanks

Comment: Compare `who` to `who -a`.